# TIMESTAMP on UPDATE doesn't work with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a **feeddate** column with the info below..

> type : timestamp
>   attributes : on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   default : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

and when I used PHP to **INSERT INTO** the rows with this code ..

```
$badgefeed = "INSERT INTO d VALUES ('','".$userID."','Badge','','".$badgeNAME."','".$badgeTYPE."','".$badgelv."','','')";
$badgefeedQ = mysql_query($badgefeed);
```

(feeddate is on the last column that NULL)

This feeddate doesn't update and be like 0000-00-00 00:00:00
but it's gonna work when I used PHP to **UPDATE** something that already had in the table.

Did I do anything wrong with my feeddate structure or the INSERT code is incorrect ?

Comment: insead of `''` use `null`. That way it will get updated properly.

Comment: @AlexTartan No, null does not lead to set the default value for that column on insert. It has to be omitted

Comment: @AlexTartan Hey thank you so much. It's work !

Comment: @NongkarnttNitchkarnt, added an answer and a bit of explanation. Happy it  helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
$badgefeed = "INSERT INTO d VALUES ('','".$userID."','Badge','','".$badgeNAME."','".$badgeTYPE."','".$badgelv."','')";
```

Don't use any value for the last column as you are using the timestamp as default value in MySQL. Just omit the last (blank) value from your query. In such a way, value for the concerned column will be considered null and thus default timesamp will will be used.

Comment: You need to specify the list of columns for this to work in the insert statement. If you omit the list of columns, then you need to specify a value for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Insead of `''` use `null`.
This way, `mysql` manages the value itself.

If you specify any value, the server will take your value, regardless other triggers, settings.

If you don't include the column in the insert statement or leave it blank (null), it will get set by the server, according to the defaults. In this case the default being `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: There is only one catch: if the timestamp field is nullable, then this solution sets the value to null, not to the actual timestamp on insertion. The safest way is to omit the field from the insert statement altogether.

Comment: @Shadow, yep! but in this case, `default : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it's safe

Comment: Default value and being nullable are 2 different animals!

Comment: Quote from mysql documentation on Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME: "In addition, you can initialize or update any TIMESTAMP column to the current date and time by assigning it a NULL value, unless it has been defined with the NULL attribute to permit NULL values. " http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html